# Behaviour of each iterator in ruby

Tags: ruby

Why does this block of code output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and not `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x.each do |a|
  a + 1
end
```

I viewed the source of `each` at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each. Something like this is written there.

```
              VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me go through the key lines.

From this one it follows 'ary' is logically equal to array. Note the line is absent from newer versions of Ruby such as 2.4.0!

```
volatile VALUE ary = array;
```

I skip RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR since a block is given. Refer to its source in at include/ruby/intern.h.

Next, we go into a 'for' for each element of 'ary' array.

Next is the line that puzzles you, I believe. First, it take i-th element from 'ary' array via RARRAY_AREF macro. Second, it passed the element's value to the block given (i.e 'a + 1') via rb_yield. Thus, it does not store anything.

```
rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
```

Since nothing was written at rb_yield, the function return the 'ary' array which is [see above] is input 'array'.

Comparing it to 'map!' may help you further:

```
static VALUE rb_ary_collect_bang(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    rb_ary_modify(ary);
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_ary_store(ary, i, rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i)));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Note 'rb_ary_store' function call inside the 'for' loop. It is the thing! It rb_yield-s just like in 'each' variant, but it does not throw away the result returned. The result is stored at i-th element of our [beloved] 'ary' array.

Comment: Personally, I find [this implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/array.rb#L64-L77) much easier to read than YARV's.

Answer (score 3):

It outputs the object, you're calling `each` on, because this is the return value of `each`.

If you want to just print the `a + 1`, you should actually make it being output:

```
x.each do |a|
  puts a + 1
end
```

Or, if your desired result is  `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` - you want [Enumerable#`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), not `each`.

```
x.map { |a| a + 1 }
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: i tried with  puts a + 1...but this is printing both [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @AmitAuddy the Ruby code you posted in question doesn't print anything. It's the interactive interpreter (`irb`) the one that prints the value of each evaluated expression. When the code is executed using `ruby` it doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @axiac yes. I am talking about the output from irb.